# How to display serial number in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i am using windows application with C#.
I want to display Serial number in datagridview.

Comment: is grid rows are fixed?

Comment: Rows are most of not fixed in datagridview

Comment: Krushnakant Ladani is right,grid's rows not fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind DataBindingComplete event of datagridview.

```
private void gridStateZone_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadSerial(gridStateZone);
    }


private void LoadSerial(DataGridView grid)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
        {
            grid.Rows[row.Index].HeaderCell.Value = string.Format("{0}  ", row.Index + 1).ToString();
            row.Height = 25;
        }
    }
```

It's work for me.

Answer (score 4):

In WinForms Applications, to display the row number in the row header, we could use the RowPostPaint event of DataGridView control.

> Usage: **Suppose grid is named as dgvUserDetails**

**Delegate**

```
this.dgvUserDetails.RowPostPaint += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventHandler(this.dgvUserDetails_RowPostPaint);
```

**Code**

```
private void dgvUserDetails_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(dgvUserDetails.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor))
        {
              e.Graphics.DrawString((e.RowIndex + 1).ToString(), e.InheritedRowStyle.Font, b, e.RowBounds.Location.X + 10, e.RowBounds.Location.Y + 4);
        }
}
```

Don’t try to manipulate the Code part much because the X and Y are calculated co-ordinates in the row header area or you can customizse test it yourself to see the various results.

**Result**

[image]

[link](https://baidharsh.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/display-row-number-in-winforms-datagridview/)

Answer (score 2):

```
private void grid_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e )
    {
        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(((DataGridView)sender).RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString((e.RowIndex + 1).ToString(), e.InheritedRowStyle.Font, b, e.RowBounds.Location.X + 10, e.RowBounds.Location.Y + 4);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void DgvSupplierInfo_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvSupplierInfo == null)
            return;

        int sno = 1;
        string columnName = "columnName";
        string headerText = "headerText";

        if (dgvSupplierInfo.Columns.Contains(columnName))
            dgvSupplierInfo.Columns.Remove(columnName);
        {
            dgvSupplierInfo.Columns.Add(columnName, headerText);
        }

        dgvSupplierInfo.Columns[columnName].DisplayIndex = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvSupplierInfo.Rows)
            row.Cells[columnName].Value = sno++;

        dgvSupplierInfo.AutoResizeColumns();
    }
```