# Adding Serial# column programatically using DbContext

Tags: c#, winforms, dbcontext

How can a serial# (auto-incremented integer) column be added on-the-fly, at the 0th index, to the Data/List returned by a data-fetching command such as follows:

```
var averages = dbContextObj.MinuteAverages
               .Where(x => x.ID == selectedID &&
                           x.Timestamp >= startDate &&
                           x.Timestamp <= endDate)
               .OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp).ToList();
```

This column along with actual data from `MinuteAverages` has to be added to a `DataGridView` and should be bound to corresponding retrieved records (as I assume it would) for sorting purposes.

Comment: Better, simpler and working answer is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697917/how-to-display-serial-number-in-datagridview

Answer (score 0):

**First method**

Create a *ViewModel* to extends the *MinuteAverage* properties 
You can use [*Automapper*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper/) to make your code easier

```
//remembet to add nuget and => using AutoMapper;
public class AveragesVM:MinuteAverage //inherit from your entity class retrieved from dbContextObj.MinuteAverages 
{
     public int Id{get;set;}
     public AveragesVM:MinuteAverage(MinuteAverage minuteAverage)
     {
        var mapper= Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<MinuteAverage,AveragesVM>());
        return  mapper.Map<AveragesVM>(minuteAverage);
     }
}
```

And then, convert the *MinuteAverage* collection to an *AveragesVM* collection with the Id filled.

```
//remeber to add using System.Linq;

var averagesWithId = averages.Select(new AveragesVM(x))
                    .ForEach(x=> x.Id= averages.Indexof(x));
```

**Second method**

Also you can listen to databound event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
        GridViewRow row = e.Row;
        row.Attributes["id"]=grdNews.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Badulake. I want to use your first solution as it seems more appropriate and efficient. But VS issues error on `new AveragesVM(x)` at `x` that it doesn't exist in current context. Also ForEach is not being recognized. Do I have to include some reference or what?

Comment: Secondly I think (from `GridView1_RowDataBound`) that your solution might be valid for ASP.NET env while I have asked question for WinForms as indicated by the tag.

Comment: I detailed more the response @PihuMehra

Comment: Your updated code issues an error on `var mapper= Mapper.Initialize...` that "cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable" (because `Initialize()` returns `void`)

Comment: Also, the constructor cannot return any value while you are returning the Mapping.

Comment: These are just guidelines. Not compiling code. Make the transformations you consider to make it compiling and working and then come back to tell us if that worked